# using jquery-1.10.2.min and jquery-1.7.1.min in one template

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, lucene.net, jquery-1.7, jquery-1.10

I am working on project that used a template work with  "jquery-1.10.2.min".
And I use Lucene.net for my search. Lucene.NET work with "jquery-1.7.1.min".
when I use "jquery-1.7.1.min" for the template some section working bad, and when I use "jquery-1.10.2.min" for Lucene.NET autocompelete search do not work!

Is there any solution?

Comment: http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/ otherwise use jquery.noConflict()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly after my searches I find best Solution here :

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/

Answer (score 0):

Visit : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

& Look Example: Load two versions of jQuery (not recommended). Then, restore jQuery's globally scoped variables to the first loaded jQuery.